# how to find the shortest relationship between the two nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have multiple relationships in my graph. I wanted to find the shortest relationship between the two nodes.

I have two types of nodes:
1.person
2.Company

and many relationships between those nodes such as phone, email, address, etc.

[Here is the screenshot of my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI7BI.png)

I tried doing:
`MATCH (r)-[q:*1..3]-(p)  return type(q)`

But it gave an error message:

```
Invalid input '*': expected whitespace or a rel type name (line 1, column 14 (offset: 13))
```

I also tried `MATCH (r)-[*]-(p)  return *` but it is taking the infinite time. I also tried the query via indexing to fasten the process but still no luck.

Please let me know how to find the shortest path between the nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 2 errors in this query:

```
MATCH (r)-[q:*1..3]-(p)  return type(q)
```

1. The colon (":") should only be used in a relationship pattern in front of a type name. Since in your case you did not want to specify a type name, you need to omit the colon.
2. Since `q` is used in a variable-length path pattern, its value will be a *list* of relationships.

Here is a query that should actually return what your query seemed to be attempting to return:

```
MATCH ()-[qs*..3]-()
UNWIND qs AS q
RETURN TYPE(q)
```

Now, if you want to find the shortest path between 2 nodes (as indicated by your question subject), see @DaveBennett's answer (assuming he fixes the issues I mentioned in a comment to his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have you consulted the Neo4j Cypher Manual per chance on `shortestPath`?

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path

If you wanted to find the shortest path...

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((r:person {name: 'Sandeep Garg'})-[q*1..3]-(p:Company {name: 'Gopal Prjapati'}))  
RETURN path
```

If you wanted to find the realtionships in the shortest path

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((r:person {name: 'Sandeep Garg'})-[q*1..3]-(p:Company {name: 'Gopal Prjapati'}))  
RETURN realtionships(path)
```

Comment: A couple of easy fixes are needed to make your queries work: You need to eliminate the colon from the variable-length relationship patterns, and you should not have `p` defined in 2 different ways in each query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It worked for me. there was an error of colon which @cybersam mentioned. I figured it out. thanks

Comment: yep - shoddy work on my part :) At least @cybersam was there for quality control